# Segmentation fault on parallelization with OpenMP(Parallel for)

Tags: c++, openmp

When I run my code without "parallel for" it works perfectly . But when I use "Parallel for"
, I receive Core dumped error . The problem occurs in calling operators .
The operators works perfectly when I comment the parallel for syntax .

This is the part of my code :

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <cmath>
> #include <omp.h>
> #include <Eigen/Core>
> #include <Eigen/Dense>
>
> #include "NEGF.h"
>
> using namespace std;
> using namespace Eigen;
>
> void NEGF::PHONON(){
>
>     cout << endl << "*********************************" << endl ;
>     cout         << "PHONON calculations is running ...   " << endl ;
>     cout         << "*********************************" << endl ;
>
>     int Nhw0, ii, kk, iE,n_hw, iK,iKx, iteta, iq , XY, YX;
>   double Kp ,Kt,Ktx , V_Value,gamma,dteta,Nw,KBT;
>     Nhw0=floor(hw0/dE);
>
>     vector< complex<double> > Gn_ems(nZ*nZ*nK);
>     vector< complex<double> > Gn_abs(nZ*nZ*nK);
>     vector< complex<double> > Vpop(nZ*nZ*nK);
>     MatrixXcd M_Gamma(nZ,nZ) ;
>     MatrixXcd M_Self(nZ,nZ) ;
>     vector<double> teta(40);
>
>     gamma=q*hw0/(0.5/epsAC -0.5/epsDC);
>     KBT=Temp*0.026/300;
>     Nw=1/(exp(hw0/(KBT))-1);
>
>     for(ii=0;ii<teta.size();ii++){
>       teta[ii]= M_PI*ii/(teta.size()-1) ;
>     }
>
>     dteta=teta[1]-teta[0];
> #pragma omp parallel for
>   for(iKx=0;iKx<nK;iKx++){
>     Ktx=KX[iKx];
>     for(iE=0;iE<nE;iE++){
>         M_Gamma.setZero(nZ,nZ);
>         M_Self.setZero(nZ,nZ);
>
>         for(iteta=0;iteta<teta.size();iteta++){
>             for(iK=0;iK<nK;iK++){
>               Kt=KX[iK];
>               if(iE+Nhw0 < nE){
>                   n_hw=iE+Nhw0 ;
>                   XY=1;
>                   operator()(Gn,Gn_ems,iK,n_hw,XY);
>               }
>               else{
>                   XY=0;
>                   operator()(Gn,Gn_ems,iK,iE,XY);
>               }
>
>               if(iE-Nhw0>=0){
>                   n_hw=iE-Nhw0 ;
>                   YX=1;
>                   operator()(Gn,Gn_abs,iK,n_hw,YX);
>               }
>               else{
>                   YX=0;
>                   operator()(Gn,Gn_abs,iK,iE,YX);
>               }
>                     Kp=sqrt(pow(Ktx,2)+pow(Kt,2)-2*Kt*Ktx*cos(teta[iteta])) ;
>                     for(ii=0;ii<nZ;ii++){
>                         for(kk=0;kk<nZ;kk++){
>                             V_Value=exp(-sqrt(pow(Kp,2)+pow(qD,2))*abs(ii-kk)*dZ)*
>                                     (1-pow(qD,2)*abs(ii-kk)*dZ/(2*sqrt(pow(Kp,2)+pow(qD,2)))-
>                                             pow(qD,2)/(2*(pow(Kp,2)+pow(qD,2))))/(pow(Kp,2)+pow(qD,2));
>                             operator()(Vpop,0,ii,kk,iK,V_Value);
>                         }
>                     }
>
>               }
>             for(iq=0;iq<nK;iq++){
>               for(ii=0;ii<nZ;ii++){
>                   for(kk=0;kk<nZ;kk++){
>                       M_Gamma(ii,kk)=M_Gamma(ii,kk)+ (2*M_PI*dK*KX[iq]*dteta*gamma*M_PI/pow(M_PI*2,2))
>                               *operator()(Vpop,ii,kk,iq)*(operator()(Gn_abs,ii,kk,iq)+operator()(Gn_ems,ii,kk,iq));
>                   }
>               }
>             }
>             }
>         M_Self=-Xi*(M_Gamma-M_Gamma.adjoint().eval())/2;
>         operator()(GAMPOP,M_Gamma,iKx,iE);
>         operator()(POPSELF,M_Self,iKx,iE);
>
>         }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Post the stack trace...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sharing all the iterator values by default. Thus you will surely seg fault. I imagine this is why the `default(none)`  is recommended.

To debug set `#pragma omp parallel for default(none)` and then decide if the variables should be shared or private for each thread.